# Syntax for jQuery ajax POST when Rest Method has a single string parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

WebAPI method looks like:

```
[HTTPPost]
public IHttpActionResult POST([FromBody] string myStringHere)
{
    if (myStringHere == null) {
        return BadRequest("Dont continue below ");

    //YAY... do stuff below...
}
```

(if it's relevant, I'm using Net Full Fx 4.6.x)

jQuery Ajax call looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: C_URL_Endpoint,
    contentType: 'text/plain', // 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    data: "="+ ??????? 
})
.done(etc)
.fail(etc)
```

I tried various combinations of contentType: and data: with no luck, always receiving null server side.

I am sure I've done this before, there was a peculiar syntax involving the data: format with an = sign, but I cannot recall what it was;

Preferably, please DON'T tell me to use contentType: application/json, and I don't wish to change the server-side method signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Ajax syntax in the question was almost correct.

I had a bug in my code that was rendering contentType:'useless,no effect whatsoever', because I was also passing a headers: object, which was setting Content-Type to application/json all the time!

the answer is

```
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
data: "=write some string here"
```

Server method will then receive everything to the right of =